# How to parse the first attribute in an XML string?

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios7

Can you help me with this program i'm trying to parse an xml file and my XML Looks like:
This my XML

```
<pre>
<site>
<restaurant capacite="450" heure_debut_service="11:30:00" heure_fin_service="14:00:00" nom="LE MARCHE">
        <disponibilite>
            <d i="haute" o="0" t="0"/>
            <d i="haute" o="-17" t="10"/>
            <d i="haute" o="-13" t="20"/>
            <d i="haute" o="42" t="30"/>
            <d i="haute" o="109" t="40"/>
            <d i="haute" o="222" t="50"/>
            <d i="complet" o="298" t="60"/>
            <d i="complet" o="323" t="70"/>
            <d i="complet" o="315" t="80"/>
            <d i="complet" o="302" t="90"/>
            <d i="faible" o="285" t="100"/>
            <d i="faible" o="255" t="110"/>
            <d i="haute" o="213" t="120"/>
            <d i="haute" o="152" t="130"/>
            <d i="haute" o="96" t="140"/>
            <d i="haute" o="49" t="150"/>
        </disponibilite>
        <fluidite>
            <f i="fluide" o="0" t="0"/> // I want to search this value i="fluide"
            <f i="fluide" o="13" t="10"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="25" t="20"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="35" t="30"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="84" t="40"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="80" t="50"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="67" t="60"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="66" t="70"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="61" t="80"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="56" t="90"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="48" t="100"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="34" t="110"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="20" t="120"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="13" t="130"/>
            <f i="fluide" o="9" t="140"/>
            <f i="12" o="3" t="150"/>
        </fluidite>
        <stand nom="PIZZA PASTA ETC.">
            <fluidite>
                <f i="pertubé" t="0"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="10"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="20"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="30"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="40"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="50"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="60"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="70"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="80"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="90"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="100"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="110"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="120"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="130"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="140"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="150"/>
            </fluidite>
            <menuSemaine>
                <menu jour="0">
                    <plat>
                        Kebab   Sauce yaourt
                    </plat>
                </menu>
            </menuSemaine>
        </stand>
        <stand nom="COCOTTES">
            <fluidite>
                <f i="fluide" t="0"/> //My code search this value "i=fluide"
                <f i="fluide" t="10"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="20"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="30"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="40"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="50"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="60"/>
                <f i="ralenti" t="70"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="80"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="90"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="100"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="110"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="120"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="130"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="140"/>
                <f i="fluide" t="150"/>
            </fluidite>
            <menuSemaine>
                <menu jour="0">
                    <plat>
                        Escalope de dinde, crème forestière, macaronis
                    </plat>
                </menu>
            </menuSemaine>
        </stand>
</site>     
</pre>
```

My parser code is like this:

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

  self.currentElement = elementName;

  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"restaurant"])
  {

  ```
  self.aArticle = [[Article alloc]init];
  self.aArticle.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"art%d",self.counter];
  self.counter++;
  ```

  }

  //Fluidite
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"f"])
  {
      self.aArticle.datePublished2 = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"t"];
      if ([self.aArticle.datePublished2 isEqualToString:@"0"])
      {
          self.aArticle.datePublished = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"i"];
      }
  }

}

My code search this value "i=fluide".
stand -> nom="COCOTTES" -> fluidite -> f i="fluide"

but I want this value
stand -> restaurant -> fluidite -> f -> i="fluide" (the first line 
Any help would be appreciated......

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) class on GitHub as it will save you a lot of time. I use this in many different projects. The methods that will most likely be of interest to you are `+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLFile:(NSString *)path;` and `+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLData:(NSData *)data;`

You will end up with a nested NSDictionary object that you can traverse using standard key/value operations or using blocks as shown below

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                          usingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {

}];
```

Comment: Thank You for help.
I'm a beginner in xcode.
How to use this code.
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                          usingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
}];
with my function can you show an example?